# Training did not improve the model performance on validation data

Tags: validation, tensorflow, keras, loss

I trying to train my Resnet-50 network on a database which collects 5968 images for training and 1492 for validation (746 classes with 8 images/class for training and 2 images/class for validation).  I used ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory method to get labels from folders

My problem is that during the training, the accuracy of the training was increasing and the loss was decreasing which is good. In fact, the validation accuracy was very low (around 0.003) and there is no improvement. Also the validation loss is very high and still oscillating into very high values!!

Here is my code

```
 import numpy as np
 from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
 import resnet
 import json
 from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
 import keras
 import pydot as pyd
 keras.utils.vis_utils.pydot = pyd

 data_path_l =".\\TRAIN\\left_750\\"

 test_data_path_l =".\\TEST\\left_750\\"



num_classes=746
train_images=5968
val_images=1492
batch_size=32
epochs=500

img_channels=3
img_rows=224
img_cols=224

input_imgen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range = 0.2, 
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               rotation_range=5.,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

valid_imgen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_it = input_imgen.flow_from_directory(directory=data_path_l,target_size=(img_rows,img_cols),
                                      color_mode="rgb",
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      class_mode="categorical",
                                      shuffle=False,
                                      )

valid_it = valid_imgen.flow_from_directory(directory=test_data_path_l,target_size=(img_rows,img_cols),
                                      color_mode="rgb",
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      class_mode="categorical",
                                      shuffle=False,
                                      )

model = resnet.ResnetBuilder.build_resnet_50((img_channels, img_rows, img_cols), num_classes)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

filepath=".\\conv2D_models\\model-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}.hdf5"

mc = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, save_weights_only=False, verbose=1, 
monitor='loss', mode='min')


history=model.fit_generator(train_it,
                    steps_per_epoch= train_images // batch_size,
                    validation_data = valid_it, 
                    validation_steps = val_images // batch_size,
                    epochs = epochs,callbacks=[mc],
                    shuffle=False)
model.save('resnet2D_1sample.h5')
```

and here is a part of training epochs:

```
        Epoch 00059: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-59-3.6342.hdf5
    Epoch 60/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 262s 1s/step - loss: 3.6074 - acc: 0.4078 - val_loss: 12.1131 - val_acc: 0.0034

    Epoch 00060: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-60-3.6084.hdf5
    Epoch 61/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 276s 1s/step - loss: 3.5681 - acc: 0.4236 - val_loss: 12.0455 - val_acc: 0.0034

    Epoch 00061: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-61-3.5683.hdf5
    Epoch 62/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 100s 536ms/step - loss: 3.4684 - acc: 0.4415 - val_loss: 10.2444 - val_acc: 0.0068

    Epoch 00062: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-62-3.4674.hdf5
    Epoch 63/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 516ms/step - loss: 3.4523 - acc: 0.4414 - val_loss: 11.6459 - val_acc: 0.0062

    Epoch 00063: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-63-3.4530.hdf5
    Epoch 64/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 516ms/step - loss: 3.3837 - acc: 0.4782 - val_loss: 12.3293 - val_acc: 0.0062

    Epoch 00064: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-64-3.3847.hdf5
    Epoch 65/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 3.2915 - acc: 0.5045 - val_loss: 12.8812 - val_acc: 0.0034

    Epoch 00065: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-65-3.2928.hdf5
    Epoch 66/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 517ms/step - loss: 3.2506 - acc: 0.5129 - val_loss: 13.2886 - val_acc: 0.0034

    Epoch 00066: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-66-3.2527.hdf5
    Epoch 67/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 3.2511 - acc: 0.5123 - val_loss: 14.4090 - val_acc: 0.0034

    Epoch 00067: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-67-3.2530.hdf5
    Epoch 68/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 97s 519ms/step - loss: 3.2632 - acc: 0.5163 - val_loss: 16.2364 - val_acc: 0.0027

    Epoch 00068: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-68-3.2650.hdf5
    Epoch 69/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 517ms/step - loss: 3.1477 - acc: 0.5585 - val_loss: 16.2729 - val_acc: 0.0021

    Epoch 00069: saving model to .\conv2D_models\tmodel-69-3.1487.hdf5
    Epoch 70/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 516ms/step - loss: 2.9347 - acc: 0.6099 - val_loss: 16.7732 - val_acc: 0.0014

    Epoch 00070: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-70-2.9369.hdf5
    Epoch 71/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 2.7118 - acc: 0.6715 - val_loss: 15.4640 - val_acc: 0.0075

    Epoch 00071: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-71-2.7134.hdf5
    Epoch 72/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 517ms/step - loss: 2.6145 - acc: 0.6835 - val_loss: 16.2367 - val_acc: 0.0055

    Epoch 00072: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-72-2.6159.hdf5
    Epoch 73/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 517ms/step - loss: 2.5492 - acc: 0.6816 - val_loss: 16.8155 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00

    Epoch 00073: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-73-2.5503.hdf5
    Epoch 74/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 516ms/step - loss: 2.5743 - acc: 0.6786 - val_loss: 14.1867 - val_acc: 0.0021

    Epoch 00074: saving model to .\conv2D_models\model-74-2.5759.hdf5
    Epoch 75/500
    186/186 [==============================] - 96s 516ms/step - loss: 2.5295 - acc: 0.6962 - val_loss: 12.3790 - val_acc: 0.0055
```

could anyone suggest to me some potential raisons that leads to this strange training behavior because it's been blocking me for a week..

Comment: Add more data, 8 images per class is far too few!!

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen does data augmentation resolve my problem?

Comment: The number of images is very less and the model could not generalise better. Try Data Augmentation.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I have tried some real time data augmentation as illustrated in the code but this didn't actually solve the problem.. should I process some data augmentation and save the obtained images then try retry the training?